# Fastest way to calculate matrix elements

Tags: r, optimization, matrix

I'm working on something which requires me to calculate the elements of a large square matrix repeatedly. The process involves reading data stored in another matrix, and then calculating the matrix elements.  Presently I am using a double *for* loop to do this.

```
library(matrixcalc)

data <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=1000)

for(x in 1:ncol(data)){
   for(y in 1:ncol(data)){
       matrix[x,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x]-data[,y],2))
   }
}
```

The problem is that this is extremely slow since my matrix is very large. What is the fastest alternative to this procedure?

Comment: Please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) of what you are doing now with the `for` loops. Answers will depend on the calculations you do inside the loops.

Comment: It's still not reproducible because we don't have `entrywise.norm` nor `data`.

Comment: @Roland *entrywise.norm* is a function in the matrixcalc package, *data* is a 3x2500 matrix

Comment: @Comp_Warrior why should *we* do extra work to answer *your* problem? Please read  [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381). A simple toy example will do. How hard is it to add a couple of lines of code... e.g.  `require(matrixcalc) ; data <- matrix( 1 , 3 , 2500 )`.

Comment: @Comp_Warrior or `data <- matrix( 1 ,  2500 ,3)`.....

Comment: @SimonO101 I have implemented the suggestions, but will only accept the answer when I am able to see if they are quicker with my data. (later)

Comment: @Comp_Warrior no you haven't. Check your code. You have a single column matrix filled with 3's. If all you do is copy/paste from the ***example*** I gave you (i.e. intended as a jumping off point not an answer) all you will do is fill a 3 row, 2500 column matrix with 1's. Totally meaningless for this problem. Do a modicum of work on your own and make a *SMALL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short and very fast:

```
mat <- exp(-as.matrix(dist(t(data))))
```

I would also recommend the `fields::rdist` function as a faster alternative to `dist` for computing the matrix of euclidean distances, so if loading the package is not an issue, consider:

```
library(fields)
mat <- exp(-rdist(t(data)))
```

---

To give you an idea of the speed improvement:

```
data <- matrix(runif(3000), nrow=3, ncol=1000)

OP <- function(data) {
  require(matrixcalc)
  mat <- matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))
  for(x in 1:ncol(data)){
    for(y in 1:ncol(data)){
      mat[x,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x]-data[,y],2))
    }
  }
  mat
}

flodel1 <- function(data) exp(-as.matrix(dist(t(data))))
flodel2 <- function(data) {
  require(fields)
  exp(-rdist(t(data)))
}

system.time(res1 <- OP(data))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 22.708   2.080  24.602 
system.time(res2 <- flodel1(data))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.112   0.025   0.136 
system.time(res3 <- flodel2(data))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.048   0.000   0.049
```

*(Note that in the case of `OP` and `flodel2`, these runtimes do not include the loading of the packages as they had been loaded prior to the tests.)*

Comment: +1 Wow. I don't think you should have removed your comment explaining why you downvoted the OP, because it is (still) very relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This should be considerably faster:

```
nc <- ncol(data)

mat <- diag(nc)

for(x in 2:nc){
   for(y in 1:x){
       mat[x, y] <- exp(-(sum((data[ , x] - data[ , y])^2) ^ .5))
   }
}

mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[upper.tri(mat)]
```

Answer (score 1):

R language uses **[column-major-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)** arrays. Changing the for loops order can give a boost in performance. Because this way, you access the memory in a more contiguous shape, enabling cpu-cache advantages.

```
 for(y in 1:dim) //outer is y now
 {
    for(x in 1:dim) //now x is count inside
    {
        matrix[x,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x]-data[,y],2))
    }
 }
```

Your "matrix" is 2D-array right?

If you need even more speed, you can unroll some of inner loop to have less branching load for cpu and better caching/prefetching.

```
 for(y in 1:dim) 
 {
    for(x in 1:(dim/8)) //lets imagine dimension is a multiple of 8
    {
        matrix[x,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+1,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+1]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+2,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+2]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+3,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+3]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+4,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+4]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+5,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+5]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+6,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+6]-data[,y],2))
        matrix[x+7,y]=exp(-entrywise.norm(data[,x+7]-data[,y],2))
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colSums` instead of the inner loop. Based on the answer by @Sven Hohenstein:

```
nc <- ncol(data)

mat <- diag(nc)

for(x in 2:nc){
  mat[x, 1:x] <- exp(-(colSums((data[ , 1:x] - data[ ,x])^2) ^ .5))
}

mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[upper.tri(mat)]
```